# Don't log emails sent in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, meteor

When I'm in development mode, `Email.send` prints the email contents in the console. It's great if I want to test whether the email works, but makes things difficult if emails are long and I'd like to debug something else.

Is there an easy way to disable logging of email contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stuff that comes on the console is purely for development only. If you pass an environmental variable for `MAIL_URL` the email data will no longer be printed to the console, maybe something like `smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1:25` might trick it into working.

The exact source of the part that prints it out to the console is the `devModeSend` function in  `packages/email/email.js`. It doesn't send anything, rather just prints out to the console if the email hosts aren't configured.